# Определение падежей

Tags: падежи

Здравствуйте, помогите разобраться в определении падежа слова НОЧЬ в предложении: Всю ночь огонь костра то разгорается, то гаснет. Я считаю, что винительный, но есть мнение что это слово стоит в предложном падеже.

Answer (score 4):

Падеж здесь, естественно, винительный.
Предложный падеж невозможен без предлога. И форма у него "(о) ночи".

Answer (score 2):

Много лет назад моя школьная учительница учила нас определять падеж по слову "коза". До сих пор ничего более удобного не нашла, особенно при определении винительного падежа.
Всю ночь (всю "козу") огонь костра то разгорается, то гаснет. Окончание -у: значит вин. падеж.

Comment: А вы уверены, что при замене "ночь" на "козу" фраза не превратиться в диагноз?

Comment: ))) Нас учили подставлять "лису". Сразу будет видно окончание, а смысл не так важен, хотя иногда очень веселые предложения получаются.